# Github presubmit - bazel tests on only affected targets

Tags: github-actions, bazel

We're writing a GitHub Presubmit that only is supposed to run tests on test targets where their dependencies have been impacted in the PR.

We do so by:

1. Getting the affected targets (assume loaded in $TARGETS variable)
2. `bazel query "rdeps(//path/to/unittests/..., set($TARGETS))" > test`
3. `bazel test $(<test)`

The issue is, if (2) doesn't find any targets to test, (3) will fail with an error status code (it seems like bazel test on no targets returns an error).

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: https://github.com/Tinder/bazel-diff

Comment: https://github.com/bazel-contrib/target-determinator